# Java pattern matching going to infinite loop

Tags: java, regex

A friend gave me this piece of code and said there is a bug. And yes, this code runs for ever.

The answer I got is:

> It runs for >10^15 years before printing anything.

```
public class Match {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(aa|aab?)+");
         int count = 0;
         for(String s = ""; s.length() < 200; s += "a")
             if (p.matcher(s).matches())
                 count++;
         System.out.println(count);
     }
}
```

I didn't really understand why am I seeing this behavior, I am new to java, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you print the counts (and timestamps) for every iteration to see when it goes berserk?

Comment: Note that there is a (somewhat large) difference between "infinite" and "10^15 years".  You can reduce/increase the compute time of your loop (by running it on different hardware, for example), but I dare you to reduce the compute time of "while(true) {}" without altering the code!  All that being said, it doesn't hurt to treat this example as an infinite loop for the purposes of debugging.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The pattern you are using is known as an evil regex according to OWASP (they know what they're talking about most of the time):

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

It basically matches `aa` OR `aa` or `aab` (since the b is optional by addition of `?`)

A Regex like this is vulnerable to a ReDoS or Regex Denial of Service Attack.

So yes, sort out what you want to match.  I suggest in the above example you should simply match `aa`, no need for groups, repitition or alternation:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aa");
```

Also as someone pointed out, who now deleted his post, you should not use += to append to strings.  You should use a [StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead:

```
public class Match {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aa");
    StringBuffer buffy = new StringBuffer(200);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
      buffy.append("a")
      if (p.matcher(buffy.toString()).matches()){
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

Comment: So is it an infinite loop, or just a really, really long loop?

Comment: it is REALLY REALLY long depending on the string length

Comment: A small detail: `ab|cd` matches `abd` or `acd`.  The `|` causes the regex to match either of the atomic expressions on either side of it.  If you want to match `ab` or `cd`, you have to group them like `(ab)|(cd)`, or using non-capturing parentheses `(?:ab)|(?:cd)`.

Comment: no, `ab|cd` matches `ab` or `cd` and offcourse `abd` because it starts with `ab` and `acd` because it ends with `cd`

Comment: OK, wow, you're totally right.  I think maybe I was thinking of the behavior of the `+`, `*`, etc.

Comment: Unless you are sharing the `StringBuffer` with multiple threads (and if so, why?), you should use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `(aa|aab?)+` is one that takes an especially long time for the regular expression engine to handle.  These are colorfully called [evil regexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS#Evil_regexes).  It is similar to the `(a|aa)+` example at the link.  This particular one is very slow on a string composed entirely of `a`s.

What this code does is check the evil regex against increasingly long strings of `a`s, up to length 200, so it certainly ought to take a long time, and it doesn't print until the loop ends.  I'd be interested to know where the 10^15 years figure came from.

### Edit

OK, the 10^15 (and in fact the entire piece of code in the question) comes from [this talk](http://strangeloop2010.com/system/talks/presentations/000/014/450/BlochLee-JavaPuzzlers.pdf), slide 37.  Thanks to zengr for that link.  The most relevant piece of information to the question is that the check for this regex takes time that is exponential in the length of the string.  Specifically it's O(2^(n/2)), so it takes 2^99 (or so) times longer to check the last string than the first one.

Comment: Slide 37: http://strangeloop2010.com/system/talks/presentations/000/014/450/BlochLee-JavaPuzzlers.pdf

Comment: Nice one!  Actually this entire talk is very interesting, but the most relevant info is that the regex check that happens here is exponential in the length of the string being scanned.  O(2^(n/2)), specifically.